# PHP set time limit for try catch

Tags: php, try-catch

I am using a class that can not be edited as it is encrypted.  The api bounces off a website that is not always available causing a delay in load times. If it takes more than 10 seconds the page starts displaying errors from the class.

Is there a way I can put a time limit on a try catch to prevent the errors and limit the time the class can take?

```
try {
    $r = $v->url($u);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $r='';
}
```

Comment: You would probably need access to the class to set a timeout value. If the class is a 3rd party script, I would check the documentation for the class for some sort of timeout property and if that is not available, contact the developer to add one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to get hacky and do weird stuff, all for the sake of this class, you could do something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.mysite.com/callUrlFunction.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
      http_build_query(array('url' => 'http://www.othersite.com')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //timeout in seconds
$r = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($curl_errno > 0) {
   $r = "";
}
```

And then in callUrlFunction.php you would have

```
<?php
try {
  $r = $v->url($_POST['url']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $r='';
}
echo $r; //or maybe json_encode($r) or serialize($r), depending on what $r is
?>
```

Of course, this is all ridiculous, because you could just curl the othersite instead of using the wrapper.  And curling yourself is weird/dumb.

Answer (score 0):

you could flush the output buffer (http://php.net/flush), so the user will start getting content as your script still running, but that would probably be messy.

I would probably create a separate script and call it from my script using shel_exec, that way you could use some external tools to set a timeout, or you could fork a separate process and check yourself for the time, when the time is more than 10 secs you could kill that process and display the error (I would probably use this option ).